# How to trim out letter in the column

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know the effective way to trim out letter in the name.  For example, the `f_name` column have `Jenny, Johnny, Doe, Ken, Smith`.

I wanted to trim out the letter in these name so it consist only the first 2 letter. Like `Je, Jo, Do, Ke, Sm` as the output for the new column.

But the letter in these name don't have equal number of letter, like `Johnny` have 6 letter and `John` have 4 letter.

Is there any effective way to trim the uneven character's length without count all the character's length in `f_name` and place all the condition to trim all names. Like these below.

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH(f_name) > 4 THEN LTRIM(f_name, 2)
```

Comment: Your question is very cryptic. Try to rephrase it

Comment: Seriously not clear...

Comment: are the names result of a query or a string like this? Do you want to anonymize this names by cuttting to two chars? What's the aim of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Oracle use [`substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114):

```
with data (f_name) as (
  select 'Jenny' from dual union all
  select 'Johnny' from dual union all
  select 'Doe' from dual union all
  select 'Ken' from dual union all
  select 'Smith' from dual
)
select substr(f_name, 1, 2)
from data
```

Returns:

```
SUBSTR(F_NAME,1,2)
------------------
Je                
Jo                
Do                
Ke                
Sm
```

Comment: Thank You, but can it be used on multiple columns and combined all the output into one new columns?

Comment: @oncik: yes that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

USE SUBSTRING

```
   CASE WHEN LENGTH(f_name) > 4 THEN SUBSTR(f_name,1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get least acronym by all names. You may write something like

```
with s as (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <(select max(LENGTH(f_name)) from your_table ))
select f_name, 
       max(sub_f_name) keep (dense_rank FIRST order by cnt, t.lvl desc) as least_acronym
select f_name
     , substr(t.f_name,-lvl) as sub_f_name
     , t.lvl
     , count(*) over (partition by substr(t.f_name,-lvl)) as cnt
  from your_table t
     , s)
     group by f_name
```

NB. Just as Idea. Not tested yet